# How to create a Kafka non persistent topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there a way I can make a Kafka topic non-persistent? I plan to use multiple consumers in a single topic but I don't want all my consumers to pick up the same messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kafka to simulate the behaviour of a queue all your consumers would be in the same `consumer group`.

[See the kafka docs for more information](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html)

> Consumers
>
> Messaging traditionally has two models: queuing and publish-subscribe.
>   In a queue, a pool of consumers may read from a server and each
>   message goes to one of them; in publish-subscribe the message is
>   broadcast to all consumers. Kafka offers a single consumer abstraction
>   that generalizes both of these—the consumer group. Consumers label
>   themselves with a consumer group name, and each message published to a
>   topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing
>   consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate processes or on
>   separate machines.
>
> If all the consumer instances have the same consumer group, then this
>   works just like a traditional queue balancing load over the consumers.

If you want to control when messages are deleted from the log you can set `retention.ms` or `retention.bytes` in the topic configuration. Be aware that these parameters will delete a message disregarding if it was consumed or not